# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1 (network image error)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a carousel for my flutter app.Here is my code:

```
 List<NetworkImage> _listOfImages = <NetworkImage>[];

 Flexible(
          child:ListView.builder(
                itemCount: post.images.length,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: false,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          _listOfImages = [];
                          for (int i = 0; i < post.images.length; i++) {
                           _listOfImages.add(NetworkImage(post.images[i].image));
                          }
                          return Column(
                                 children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                        height: MediaQuery
                                            .of(context)
                                            .size
                                            .height * 0.5,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                        child: Carousel(
                                           images: _listOfImages,
                                           autoplay: false,
                                           dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomCenter,
                                            ),
                                          ),

                                        ],
                                      );
                                    }))
```

While I am trying to run it I stumble upon a weird error which is saying :

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
```

Oh by the way I get the data necessary (i mean post.images), the object is not null.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why there is a listview and column with corousel? Same loop inside the item builder, it's not looking correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below code i hope this will help you

```
        for (int i = 0; i < post.images.length; i++) {
        _listOfImages.add(NetworkImage(post.images[i].image));
        }
      return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: _listOfImages.length == 0 ? Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : Carousel(
        images: _listOfImages,
        autoplay: false,
        dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomCenter,
      ),
    ),

  ],
),
```